How to change version of R application the .Rdata file is associated to
I have multiple versions of R installed on my Windows 10, only one of those versions is associated with .Rdata file. Now I want to change the version of R to be associated with .Rdata file. How do I do it? The official way through "Default apps" is horribly limiting:

It only says "R for Windows ... ", without being able to select version. This screen also is where I end up when going from "Control Panel".
When I go through the list of installed programs, it doesn't offer "Modify", only "Uninstall":

So, how to do it?

I figured it out! Despite some sources not recommending to change file associations via Registry, it seems like the only way. The .Rdata file association refers to "RWorkspace", and there it is possible to change the current version - in these two settings:
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RWorkspace\DefaultIcon
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RWorkspace\shell\open\command 

See the screenshot:


Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and check as answered.
